# Fixed position element pushed out of relative position element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have the following HTML markup;

```
<div id ="page_shadow">
<div id="blog_content">
     <div id="main_content_container>

       Main Content

     </div>

     <div id="swrapper">
        <div id="blog_sidebar">
          Sidebar Content
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The following CSS;

```
    #blog_sidebar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#swrapper {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}

#blog_sidebar {
    width: 330px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-top:25px;
    height:auto;
}
#main_content_container {
    width:600px;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#blog_content {
position:relative;
width:960px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
min-height:1300px;
height:auto;
background:#FFFFFF;
z-index:5;
}
#page_shadow {
background:url('../images/background_shadow.png') top center no-repeat;
padding:10px;
    margin-top:-60px;
}
```

The following javascript;

```
            <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var top = $('#blog_sidebar').offset().top - parseFloat($('#blog_sidebar').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
          var bottom = $('#blog_content').position().top+$('#blog_content').outerHeight(true) - $('#blog_sidebar').height() - 35;
          $(window).scroll(function (event) {
            // what the y position of the scroll is
            var y = $(this).scrollTop();
          
            // whether that's below the form
            if (y >= top) { //&& y <= bottom 
              // if so, ad the fixed class
              $('#blog_sidebar').addClass('fixed');
            } else {
              // otherwise remove it
              $('#blog_sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
            }
          });
        });
        </script>
```

Ok so basically there are two scenarios which occur. IF the page is loaded with the browser viewport above the `y` position before `#blog_sidebar`'s position is changed to `fixed` then the element stays within the blog_content container.

HOWEVER, if the page is loaded with if `(y >= top) = True` resulting in `$('#blog_sidebar').addClass('fixed');` the element is then pushed outside the blog_content container.

Again this only occurs if the viewport is `= or below` the trigger when the page is loaded.

For example if i were to go half way down the page and then click for the page to refresh, the browser loads the page and the element and then jumps to the position it was previously. The fixed position element shown up in the correct position for a split second and then jumps outside `#blog_content` aligning with the left of the element.

Ive got a little example to show the basics of the layout etc, but i dont think i can show exactly whats happening within jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ce3V3/

## TLDR

Since this is quite confusing. Short version is i am changing a static positioned element with a fixed position element within the DOM, which is resulting in the fixed positioned element being out of place if the window is refreshed and jumps past a certain point. I dont want the fixed position element to jump out of place if a user relaods the page and the window jumps halfway down the page.

[image]

Comment: can u please explain what you want

Comment: I want the blog_sidebar element to remain within the blog_content element when the page is reloaded with the blog_sidebar class = fixed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hushme/ce3V3/4/ like this

Comment: ok, so not allowing the window to refresh to the previous position stopped the problem altogether, BUT is it still possible to fix this issue within having to force the page to load to the top of the window.

Comment: in jfiddle page always refresh to load to the top of window

Comment: Is there a reason for that `#page_shadow { margin-top:-60px; }`? If you remove it your code will work fine

Comment: hi yes, its is a tapered box shadow I've used to surround the content. I realize i could use CSS3 to do this but i wanted to do something more permanent regardless of browser for now. Thanks for pointing that out, ill try and work around that.

Comment: ok after a little more investigation ive come to realise that the problem is coming from another div. Im loading a disqus comment box, if I scroll past the trigger point before the comment box loads when it finishes loading the sidebar is popped out of position. Anyone have any ideas as to how to avoid this?